# DocumentDB SQL check multiple values in array

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure's DocumentDB as my database. I have potentially thousands of documents and want to return all the documents that contain certain tags.

For example:

**Document 1**

```
{
  "id": "328732,
  "name": "jeff",
  "tags": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ]
}
```

**Document 2**

```
{
  "id": "54092,
  "name": "ayla",
  "tags": [
    "B",
    "D",
    "F"
  ]
}
```

**Document 3**

```
{
  "id": "98234,
  "name": "lara",
  "tags": [
    "B",
    "G",
    "H"
  ]
}
```

If I have a list of tags `["A", "F", "X"]`, the first two documents (jeff, and ayla) should be returned.
I can achieve this by using the built in function `ARRAY_CONTAINS` with several `OR` operators:

```
SELECT * 
FROM c 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.groups, "A") OR
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.groups, "F") OR
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.groups, "X")
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this. If I had hundreds of tags I would need hundreds of conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no other way to achieve what you want. You could write code that will automatically expand to a series of `ARRAY_CONTAINS` with `OR`s.